# Custom carousel codes connected to Wordpress dashboard default post

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress, I have a carousel in my custom codes, in my localhost its perfectly fine. but when I transferred inside the wordpress all Posts displayed by rows.

my goal is to slides every single Post inside my carousel.

here is my code so far:

```
              <?php
          $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'news',
            'posts_per_page' => 3,
            'orderby' => 'post_date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            );
            $posts = get_posts( $args );
            foreach ( $posts as $post ):
            setup_postdata( $post );
          ?>               

            
            
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

                <ol class="carousel-indicators black">
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>

                <div class="carousel-inner">


                  <div class="item active"> 
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                   
                         <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">  
                            <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail('imgResize'); ?>
                            <?php else : ?>
                        
                            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/image/png/default_img.png" alt="img" >
                             
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                      <div class="aa-n-about">
                        <p class="date"><?php the_time('Y.m.d'); ?></p>
                          
                          
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                            <h5 class="n-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
                        </a>
                            <p class="n-detail"><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                      </div>
                         
                    </div>
                  </div>
                    
                                            
                  
                    
                </div>
                
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glypicon glypicon-cheveron-left"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glypicon glypicon-cheveron-right"></span>
                </a>

              <!-- / News Slides -->

          </div>
            
            
 <?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

I know this issue is easy to some.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you to be saying the query works and your HTML content outputs correctly but that the slides aren't "hidden" or, in other words, aren't appearing as slides.

If that's what's happening, I suspect it's a JS problem. It looks like you're using bootstrap. Check that you're loading the Bootstrap JS required for the carousel.

Comment: hi @JBOD thank you for your response. please enlighten me. actually my BOOTRSTARP JS is perfectly fine without the default codes of wordpress. I tried to put another row slides without the default codes from wordpress and the slides is perfectly works. but the 1st slides with wordpress codes from the query are displaying in one slides.